# Hello! How would the rotating chair experiment (which explains the conservation of angular momentum) look like in vacuum or space?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, vacuum, thought-experiment

Would it look any different from what we observe in daily life?

Comment: Well, the person sitting in the chair had better be in a space suit...

Comment: yes, pretty much the same

Comment: @Wolphramjonny pretty much?

Comment: well, the chair would not be pressed against a floor (which is not important), but in terms of conservation of angular momentum , that will work in the same way